# Using a pair of values as a key

Tags: ruby, algorithm, hash, time-complexity

Very frequently I've had the need to hash a pair of values. Often, I just generate a range between num1 and num2 and hash that as a key, but that's pretty slow because the distance between those two numbers can be quite large.

How can one go about hashing a pair of values to a table? For example, say I'm iterating through an array and want to hash every single possible pair of values into a hash table, where the key is the pair of nums and the value is their sum. What's an efficient way to do this? I've also thought about hashing an an array as the key, but that doesn't work.

Also, how would one go about extending this to 3,4, or 5 numbers?

EDIT:
I'm referring to hashing for O(1) lookup in a hashtable.

Comment: Can you hash a string `'num1:num2'`?

Comment: @Dbz I wasn't sure if this would be efficient either--to convert the numbers to strings before hashing it. But if this is the best possible way then I'll certainly mark this as correct.

Comment: are the values all positive? are they integers?

Comment: was hoping for general answer-- but if that's too broad, perhaps just integers positive and negative.

Comment: Do you mean hashing as in SHA256 or do you mean hashing as in "for use within a Hash as a key"? What's the bigger problem you're trying to solve? Can you give example inputs here? Like are these numbers `1..10` or `290..3345362`?

Comment: What is the purpose of such hash table data structure? How do you use it after construction?

Comment: Thanks for the questions--editing to include the answers

Comment: @Sunny did we answer your question? If not, what else would you still like to know?

Comment: @Dbz yes-- thank you! I was unclear in my question about what I needed to hash value for-- was simply asking about using an array as a hash key. So hash[arr] instead of hash[arr.hash]. I edited earlier to explain that but I'm upvoting answers that explained otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Just do it.

You can simply hash on the array...

## Verification

Let me show a little experiment:

```
array = [ [1,2], [3,4], ["a", "b"], ["c", 5] ]

hash = {}

array.each do |e|
  e2 = e.clone

  e << "dummy"
  e2 << "dummy"

  hash[e] = (hash[e] || 0) + 1 

  hash[e2] = (hash[e2] || 0) + 1

  puts "e == e2: #{(e==e2).inspect}, e.id = #{e.object_id}, e.hash = #{e.hash}, e2.id = #{e2.object_id}, e2.hash = #{e2.hash}"
end

puts  hash.inspect
```

As you see, I take a few arrays, clone them, modify them separately; after this, we are sure that `e` and `e2` are different arrays (i.e. different object IDs); but they contain the same elements. After this, the two different arrays are used as hash keys; and since they have the same content, are hashed together.

```
e == e2: true, e.id = 19797864, e.hash = -769884714, e2.id = 19797756, e2.hash = -769884714
e == e2: true, e.id = 19797852, e.hash = -642596098, e2.id = 19797588, e2.hash = -642596098
e == e2: true, e.id = 19797816, e.hash = 104945655, e2.id = 19797468, e2.hash = 104945655
e == e2: true, e.id = 19797792, e.hash = -804444135, e2.id = 19797348, e2.hash = -804444135
{[1, 2, "dummy"]=>2, [3, 4, "dummy"]=>2, ["a", "b", "dummy"]=>2, ["c", 5, "dummy"]=>2}
```

As you see, you can not only use arrays as keys, but it also recognizes them as being the "same" (and not some weird object identity which it could also be).

## Caveat

Obviously this works only to a point. The *contents* of the arrays must recursively be well-defined with regards to hashing. I.e., you can use sane things like strings, numbers, other arrays, even `nil` in there.

## Reference

From http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html :

> Two objects refer to the same hash key when their hash value is identical and the two objects are eql? to each other.

From http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-eql-3F :

> eql?(other) → true or false
>
> Returns true if self and other are the same object, *or are both arrays with the same content* (according to Object#eql?).
>
> hash → integer
>
> Compute a hash-code for this array.
>
> Two arrays with the *same content will have the same hash code* (and will compare using eql?).

Emphasis mine.

Comment: This does seem to be the same answer as mine :) with more explanation on  how `hash` works

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a `range` or `array`, then you can also call `hash` on it and use that.

`(num1..num2).hash`
`[num1, num2].hash`

That will return a key that you can use as a hash. I have no idea if this is efficient. It does show the source code on the [range documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html#method-i-hash) and the [array documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-hash)

Another way I would do it is to turn the numbers into strings. This is the better solution if you are worried about hash collisions.

`'num1:num2'`

And the ruby-esque ways that I would solve your problem are:

`number_array.combination(2).each { |arr| my_hash[arr.hash] = arr }`
`number_array.combination(2).each { |arr| my_hash[arr.join(":")] = arr }`

Comment: The values returned by `hash` are not guaranteed to be unique to avoid collisions. They're just supposed to be mostly unique-ish.

Comment: That's the *definition* of a hash function: it maps a large(r) (potentially infinite) input space to a small(er) finite output space. The Pigeonhole Principle guarantees that there *must* be collisions.

Comment: This is true. Are hash collisions a big deal when hashing array pairs of numbers? I don't know the use case, but I doubt it; however, this is worth bringing up.

Comment: @Dbz I just mean to contrast `hash`, which seems to produce 64-bit values in newer versions of Ruby, with things like SHA512 or a UUID where those are highly unlikely to collide. As Jörg mentions, due to the pigeonhole principle and additionally due to the [Birthday Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) it's highly probable that 64-bit values will collide.

Comment: @dbz The Ruby `hash` function is intended to *minimize* collisions, not avoid them. This is the backbone of any "hash look table", as in things like Set and Hash in Ruby. In the event of a collision the hash table function just does additional comparisons, it all works out, but only because the original values are preserved.

Comment: So if collisions are in fact an issue, then I would recommend using the string solution rather than the hash one

Comment: @Dbz The string solution uses hashing under the hood, which works in the exact same way.  It is an algorithm that is *probably* fast, not guaranteed fast.  It is widely used because in practice "probably" is plenty good.

Answer (score 0):

A hash table, where the key is the pair of nums and the value is their sum:

```
h = {}
[1,4,6,8].combination(2){|ar| h[ar] = ar.sum}
p h  #=>{[1, 4]=>5, [1, 6]=>7, [1, 8]=>9, [4, 6]=>10, [4, 8]=>12, [6, 8]=>14}
```

Note that using arrays as hash keys is no problem at all. To  extend this to 3,4, or 5 numbers use `combination(3) #or 4 or 5`.